# Несколько одинаковых полей, yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здраствуйте, у меня есть таблица User и UserPhone. У одного пользователя может быть несколько номером. 
user_phone - **user_id, phone**
Связь 1 к 1
Как сделать при добавлении пользователя, несколько полей типа   `<?= $form->field($userPhone, 'phone') ?>`
Что для этого нужно, что-то в контроллере менять?

Comment: Связь в данном случае должна быть один ко многим. Один пользователь, несколько телефонов.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте массив

```
<?= $form->field($userPhone, 'phone[]') ?>
```

Пример действия:

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    foreach($model->phone as $phone){
        $userPhone = new UserPhone();
        $userPhone->phone = $model->id;
        if($userPhone->valid()){
            $this->link('userPhone', $userPhone);
        }
    }
    ...
    $transaction->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    $transaction->rollBack();

}
```

Пример не является истиной. Почитайте про варианты сохранения связей, и выберите для себя, и своей реализации, свой.